# Convert different encode charset to UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql

I have this words (and more 40 in same case) in customer databases:

1. `Aclimaç&#227;o`
2. `Aclima&ccedil&#227;o`

I need convert both to UTF-8 and save in MySQL database: Aclimação.

How I do that with PHP?

**[EDIT]**
Observation:
I need do that because, when user find specific 'district', its impossible convert in two formats, for example:

1. `Aclima&ccedil;&aatilde;o (correct)`
2. `Aclimaç&#227;o (incorrect: utf8 + html number encode)`
3. `Aclima&ccedil&#227;o (incorrect: iso + html number encode)`

I need just 1 type of encode, in my case: ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Set encoding type to UTF8 `utf8_general_ci` in database collation.

Comment: I can't do that, because all words in database it's ISO-8859-1. I need convert this words because have 2 types of conversion (&#227 and not &aatilde), and difficult the find.

Comment: Normally `html_entity_decode()` would do. But this looks one-and-a-half-times encoded. So you might need a custom replacement map and function and/or regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did the following solution, converted all data from the database, using the function:

```
mb_convert_encoding (data, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

When I read the record, do the following:

```
utf8_decode (data)
```

When I look for some record, based on the selection of sites (), I do the following:

```
utf8_encode (data)
```

And so far, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Get the values and insert them to the database after applying [html_entity_decode()](https://www.php.net/html_entity_decode) to the string.

(The second string you provided looks like it has a malformed HTML entity, is that right?)

Comment: Yes, but, this is database of my customer, and I need convert to 'correct format'. How? For sure, I dont know... I was testing a lot functions...

Comment: @PatrickMaciel If it is a single table, or just a couple, you can select all the fields and update them back with the appropriate string having been passed through the appropriate filters. And making sure that your table collation is utf8_*_*. Or you can use eis’ procedure.

Answer (score 1):

1. dump your database contents out of there using mysqldump
2. iconv the data to UTF8
3. string replace your malformed html entitys to be valid
4. use html_entity_decode to change valid html entitys to characters that they should be. note that you should give it encoding (UTF-8) as parameter, otherwise it will depend on the PHP version!
5. create new UTF-8 database into mysql
6. import the data to mysql

I don't think for example ã exists in ISO-8859-1, so you do actually need UTF-8 for it. It is not correct to have it as `&aatilde;`, that is HTML way of representing it.